# Updating app to newer react-native

Tags: react-native

I wanna update a mobile app to a newer react-native version. I followed instructions from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html), installed `react-native-git-upgrade`, went to my project's dir, ran `react-native-git-upgrade 0.40.0`, got lots of warnings like `warning: unable to unlink path/to/some/project/file: Permission denied'`, tried with `sudo`, didn't have these errors, got output that to some files patch didn't apply, to some files it was applied cleanly, and to some other files it was applied with conflicts. As the docs said, the next step should have been fixing conflicts, but after these actions, described above my project's dir is still unchanged - my editor doesn't detect any file changes, I've opened files, listed as patched with conflicts and they didn't have any changes and didn't have conflict delimiters (like `<<<<<<< ours`). Looks like nothing happened. What am I doing wrong, and how can I do it right?

Comment: 1. do not use sudo!!! Fix permissions instead (all files should be owned by you)

Comment: I, personally, use https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff, and apply patch by hand, so I will always see what changed.

Comment: The last step of the process consists in applying a Git patch. It could fail for some reasons (if so, your sources are reverted to the initial state). Can you post the whole command output (using sudo, it seems to work better)?